# Passing a list of lists to mvc controller

Tags: javascript, java, json, ajax, spring-mvc

I am using spring MVC and I want to pass data to my controller in the backend server.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/project/update")
public @ResponseBody projectWebForm update(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response,
        @RequestBody projectWebForm input){

        ..............

        }
```

I am using the @RequestBody tag to map my fields to a class called projectWebForm

In the projectWebForm class I have 3 fields

```
private String name;
private String age;
private List<List<Data>> list;
```

and below is my Data class

```
 public class Data{
  private String data1;
  private String data2;

getters setters..... 
}
```

Now in a jsp file I am writing ajax to pass data to the controller

```
function update(name,age){
var option={
    headers:{'Content-type':'application/json;charset=utf-8'},
    contentType:'application/json;charset=utf-8',
    dataType:'json',
    async:true,
    type:'post',
    data:JSON.stringify({
        name:name,
        age:age,
        list:____________ <---- ????????
    }),
    url:'<%=request.getContextPath()%>/project/update.do',
    success:function(response){
        ......
        }
    },
};
$.ajax(option);
};
```

I can pass name and age to controller easily since its only a String, now
**I need a list of lists**, so how should I structure my list so that I can map it to the RequestBody? What should the json look like in order to correctly pass it to the RequestBody? An example maybe?

Comment: Have you wrapped these inside `form`?

Comment: pass it as an array.

Answer (score 0):

```
function Form( form ){
var formData = $(form).serialize();
att=$(form).attr("action") ;
$.post(att, formData).done(function(response){

     var errorInfo="";

      if(response.status == "SUCCESS"){
          window.location.href="/";
      }
});
return true;}
```

serialize your form data and send to the server in spring mvc

```
    <form name="myForm" th:object="${demo}" th:action="@{/demo}"  method="post"
    class="stdform" id="triggerform">

            <div class="form-group">
         <label for="usr">Name:</label>
     <input type="text" th:field="*{name}" class="form-control" />
     </div>
    <div class="form-group">
         <label for="usr">hobbies:</label>
            <input  th:field="*{hobbies[0].hobbiename}" type="text" class="form-control"   />
             <input th:field="*{hobbies[1].hobbiename}" type="text" class="form-control"   />
             <input th:field="*{hobbies[2].hobbiename}" type="text" class="form-control"  />
             <input th:field="*{hobbies[3].hobbiename}" type="text" class="form-control"  />
             <input th:field="*{hobbies[4].hobbiename}" type="text" class="form-control"   />
             <input th:field="*{hobbies[5].hobbiename}" type="text" class="form-control"   />


     </div>



            <button type="button"  onclick="return Form(this.form)" class="btn btn-primary">Get Started</button>

</form>
```

the controller part

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/demo", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView demo(HttpServletRequest request) {
        logger.info("Welcome to getInboxMessage Method inside the MessageController ");
        Profile profile=(Profile)request.getSession().getAttribute("profile");
        ModelAndView model=new ModelAndView("test");
        model.addObject("demo", new Demo());
        return model;

    }

@RequestMapping(value = "/demo", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView demopostdata(@ModelAttribute Demo demo,HttpServletRequest request) {
        logger.info("Welcome to getInboxMessage Method inside the MessageController ");
        Profile profile=(Profile)request.getSession().getAttribute("profile");
        ModelAndView model=new ModelAndView("test");
        model.addObject("demo", new Demo());
        return model;

    }
```

This is the most easiest way so you avoid lot of jquery coding

Answer (score 0):

Js

```
var list = new Array();

var data = {
    data1 : getData1,
    data2 : getData2
};

list.push(data);

data:JSON.stringify({
        name:name,
        age:age,
        list: list
    }),
```

class

```
public class test {

   pirvate String name;
   private String age;
   pirvate List<data> list;

    ... s,g

}
```

controller

```
@RequestMapping(value="/project/update", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String update(HttpServletRequest request, @RequestBody test test){

      .............. // break point
      return "";

}
```

You check model(test).